# GitHub Pages with custom domain does not redirect to index.html

Tags: github, dns, github-pages, custom-domain

I have registered an A-record with my DNS that points to my GitHub repository https://github.com/gimoya/tiroltrailhead, which is hosted as a github pages page http://gimoya.github.io/tiroltrailhead. In the repositories root folder I've placed an index.html file which I assumed would be opened when going to my domain tiroltrailhead.com or to the project pages url. However, I still get a 404 - "...If this is your site, make sure that the filename case matches the URL.
For root URLs (like http://example.com/) you must provide an index.html file." How can I set up Github and/or DNS to redirect to the index.html when opening tiroltrailhead.com or gimoya.github.io/tiroltrailhead in a browser?

Comment: first you need to create `<GITHUB_USERNAME>.github.io` repository and add `CNAME` with your domain name in this repository and remove `CNAME` from `tiroltrailhead` repo.

Comment: I have both, the repository and a CNAME record!

Comment: I'm not seeing any repository `gimoya.github.io` on your github profile. 
this repository works as root application for all of your hosted `gh-pages`

Comment: ..and then I'd need to move all my gh-pages to that repository, for them to work with the custom domain, right?

Comment: ..does it really depend solely on the repo name? All other then that would be the same: A Repo, CNAME and an index.html

Comment: Originally, I created the gh-page on the command line following these instructions: https://help.github.com/articles/creating-project-pages-using-the-command-line/ - and the project is actually hosted under gimoya.github.io.. So, I guess it don't really need a repo with that name, or do I?

Comment: ohoh, it just took some time to work! It was all okay, and the index.html is working!

Comment: @Kay, it's old, but how did you do it? I've got the same problem.